# How to set gesture detector to YoutubePlayerFragment

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, android-gesture

I am using the `YoutubePlayerFragment` class to play videos. I want to add a `GestureListener`, but their is no method to set a gesture detector. I tried:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:id="@+id/player_holder"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_weight="40">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/player_fragment"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/gestureCatcher"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE       = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH       = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

    class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Toast.makeText(NonStopActivity.this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Toast.makeText(NonStopActivity.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This is how I set the gesture detector to the LinearLayout

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};

LinearLayout gestureCatcher = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gestureCatcher);
gestureCatcher.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

But the overlay blocks `YoutubePlayerFragment`. Is there a solution around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a gesture listener right on YouTubePlayerFragment object. Try setting it in your `onCreate` method with...

```
YouTubePlayerFragment frag = (YouTubePlayerFragment) 
    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id._________)
View v = frag.getView();
v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    //your code goes here
}
```

This will work as long as the seek bar and play button overlay are hidden. If they aren't that overlay consumes the gestures. It's annoying, but I don't know a good way around it except to set the player style to chromeless. This can be done with `mPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);`

Of course, that means you can't have a play button or the seek bar, but you could implement your own somehow.

Answer (score 1):

For those who had the same issue, the best way is to extend `YouTubePlayerFragment`:

```
public class DraggableYouTubePlayerFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
        final View view = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, bundle);
        FrameLayout wrapper = new FrameLayout(viewGroup.getContext()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        wrapper.addView(view);
        return wrapper;
    }
}
```